# c array malloc unknown size

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

How can I create an array of unique strings without knowing how many strings there are until I process the input file? There can be as many as 2 million strings, max length of 50.
My program is something like this. This works for 51 items then overwrites other data. I don't know how to add an element to the array, if possible.

```
main() {

    char *DB_NAMES[51]; // i thought this gave me ptrs to chunks of 51
                // but it's 51 pointers!
    char *word;

    while not eof {
        ...function to read big string 
        ...function to separate big sting into words
        ...
        processWord(ctr, DB_NAMES, word);
        ...
    }
}

processWord(int ndx, char *array1[], char *word){

    ...function to find if word already exists...

    //if word is new, store in array 
        array1[ndx]= (char *)malloc(sizeof(51)); // isn't this giving me a char[51]?    
        strcpy(array1[ndx],word);
    ...
}
```

Comment: there is no unknown size arrays in C. You have to write your own data structure like Linked List.

Comment: `array1[ndx]= (char *)malloc(sizeof(51));` yes this would be allocating a memory of 51 bytes for `array1[]` but the size would be I suppose the value of `ndx`

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the number of words in your file using the below logic and when you get the number of words in the file you can initialize the array size with the word count.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define FILE_READ "file.txt"

int main()

{
    FILE * filp;
    int count = 1;
    char c;
    filp = fopen(FILE_READ, "r");
    if(filp == NULL)
        printf("file not found\n");
    while((c = fgetc(filp)) != EOF) {
        if(c == ' ')
            count++;
    }
    printf("worrds = %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Regards,
yanivx

Comment: I did an analysis and I need 2.5 million words. My program crashes when I try to allocate that, although I have plenty of memory. I need to learn about memory.

Answer (score 0):

Better not use a fixed string length; save memory space.

```
    char **DB_NAMES = 0;    // pointer to first char * ("string") in array; initially 0
```

Pass pointer by reference so that it can be altered. Moreover, you'll want the new `ctr` value in case a new word has been stored.

```
        ctr = processWord(ctr, &DB_NAMES, word);
```

Change function `processWord` accordingly.

```
int processWord(int ndx, char ***array1a, char *word)
{   char **array1 = *array1a;
    ...function to find if word already exists...

    // if word is new, store in array
    {
        array1 = realloc(array1, (ndx+1)*sizeof*array1);    // one more string
        if (!array1) exit(1);                               // out of memory
        array1[ndx++] = strdup(word);                       // store word's copy
        *array1a = array1;                                  // return new array
    }
    return ndx;                                             // return count
}
```